# Scroll conteúdo interno div com borda Ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic, ionic3

Como fazer com que o conteúdo interno de uma `div` específica tenha `scroll` quando o texto é maior que a área?

Me foi sugerido usar o seguinte código:

**html:**

```
<ion-content id="contrato">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="head">
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <img src="assets/imgs/logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <div class="title">Termos e Condições/Política de Privacidade</div>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="inner-main">
        <h3>TERMOS E CONDIÇÕES:</h3>
        <p>
          1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras lobortis eros quis arcu vulputate ultricies.
      Fusce sodales finibus massa, eget hendrerit erat ultrices eu. Ut blandit tincidunt mattis. Suspendisse id
      varius diam. Quisque eget tincidunt ante, sed sodales neque. Nulla quis libero eleifend, ultricies justo
      scelerisque, ultricies odio. Vestibulum sit amet justo dui. Nunc rutrum diam velit, accumsan dictum elit
      dignissim in. Maecenas vitae eros pellentesque, sollicitudin nunc congue, commodo velit. Fusce ut semper
      risus. Nullam bibendum, nisi et mattis pretium, arcu nulla ultrices magna, non suscipit nibh augue non magna.
      Duis maximus lorem eget nibh fermentum, et ultricies nisl efficitur. Nam ac libero orci.
        </p>
        <p>
          2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras lobortis eros quis arcu vulputate ultricies.
      Fusce sodales finibus massa, eget hendrerit erat ultrices eu. Ut blandit tincidunt mattis. Suspendisse id
      varius diam. Quisque eget tincidunt ante, sed sodales neque. Nulla quis libero eleifend, ultricies justo
      scelerisque, ultricies odio. Vestibulum sit amet justo dui. Nunc rutrum diam velit, accumsan dictum elit
      dignissim in. Maecenas vitae eros pellentesque, sollicitudin nunc congue, commodo velit. Fusce ut semper
      risus. Nullam bibendum, nisi et mattis pretium, arcu nulla ultrices magna, non suscipit nibh augue non magna.
      Duis maximus lorem eget nibh fermentum, et ultricies nisl efficitur. Nam ac libero orci.
        </p>
        <p>
          3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras lobortis eros quis arcu vulputate ultricies.
      Fusce sodales finibus massa, eget hendrerit erat ultrices eu. Ut blandit tincidunt mattis. Suspendisse id
      varius diam. Quisque eget tincidunt ante, sed sodales neque. Nulla quis libero eleifend, ultricies justo
      scelerisque, ultricies odio. Vestibulum sit amet justo dui. Nunc rutrum diam velit, accumsan dictum elit
      dignissim in. Maecenas vitae eros pellentesque, sollicitudin nunc congue, commodo velit. Fusce ut semper
      risus. Nullam bibendum, nisi et mattis pretium, arcu nulla ultrices magna, non suscipit nibh augue non magna.
      Duis maximus lorem eget nibh fermentum, et ultricies nisl efficitur. Nam ac libero orci.
        </p>
        <p>
          4) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras lobortis eros quis arcu vulputate ultricies.
      Fusce sodales finibus massa, eget hendrerit erat ultrices eu. Ut blandit tincidunt mattis. Suspendisse id
      varius diam. Quisque eget tincidunt ante, sed sodales neque. Nulla quis libero eleifend, ultricies justo
      scelerisque, ultricies odio. Vestibulum sit amet justo dui. Nunc rutrum diam velit, accumsan dictum elit
      dignissim in. Maecenas vitae eros pellentesque, sollicitudin nunc congue, commodo velit. Fusce ut semper
      risus. Nullam bibendum, nisi et mattis pretium, arcu nulla ultrices magna, non suscipit nibh augue non magna.
      Duis maximus lorem eget nibh fermentum, et ultricies nisl efficitur. Nam ac libero orci.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <div class="footer">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col class="check" align-self-center>
          <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="concorda"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-10 class="msg_col">
          <h4 class="confirm_msg">Eu li e concordo com os Termos e Condições/Política
        de Privacidade.
          </h4>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
    <button ion-button [disabled]="!concorda" class="send" full large>Finalizar</button>
  </div>
</ion-footer>
```

**css:**

```
page-contrato {
    #contrato {
        .main {
            .head {

                .logo {
                    height: 50pt;
                }

                .title {
                    padding: 1.6rem 0;
                    font-size: 4.5vw;
                }

                ion-row {
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: center;
                }
            }

            .inner {
                padding: 1.7rem;
                max-height: 100%;

                .inner-main {
                    border: 1.5pt solid black;
                    text-align: justify;
                    overflow-y: auto scroll;
                }
            }

            .footer {
                margin-top: auto;
                margin-bottom: 0%;

                .check {
                    text-align: center;
                    padding-left: 2.2rem;
                }

                .msg_col {
                    text-align: justify;
                    padding-right: 2.2rem;
                }

                .confirm_msg {
                    font-size: 3vw;
                }

                .send {
                    color: white;
                    margin-top: 2rem;
                    background-color: color($colors, blue);
                    padding: 16px 0;
                    font-size: 1.6rem;
                    font-weight: 500;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Porém essa solução não resolve o problema, pois assim *scrolla* toda o conteúdo central, inclusive a `div` com borda. Além de ficar aquela marca de separação em baixo por causa do `<ion-footer>` o que não é a intenção.

A intenção é ter o `scroll` somente no conteúdo interno a `div`com borda, caso esse conteúdo ultrapasse o tamanho máximo dessa `div`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Respondendo minha própria pergunta**

Depois de procurar e penar por algum tempo, consegui encontrar uma solução satisfatória para o meu problema.

**html:**

```
<ion-content id="contrato">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="head">
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col text-center>
            <img src="assets/imgs/logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col text-center>
            <div class="title">Termos e Condições/Política de Privacidade</div>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="inner-main">
        <h3>TERMOS E CONDIÇÕES:</h3>
        <p>
          1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras lobortis eros quis arcu vulputate ultricies.
      Fusce sodales finibus massa, eget hendrerit erat ultrices eu. Ut blandit tincidunt mattis. Suspendisse id
      varius diam. Quisque eget tincidunt ante, sed sodales neque. Nulla quis libero eleifend, ultricies justo
      scelerisque, ultricies odio. Vestibulum sit amet justo dui. Nunc rutrum diam velit, accumsan dictum elit
      dignissim in. Maecenas vitae eros pellentesque, sollicitudin nunc congue, commodo velit. Fusce ut semper
      risus. Nullam bibendum, nisi et mattis pretium, arcu nulla ultrices magna, non suscipit nibh augue non magna.
      Duis maximus lorem eget nibh fermentum, et ultricies nisl efficitur. Nam ac libero orci.
        </p>
        <p>
          2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras lobortis eros quis arcu vulputate ultricies.
      Fusce sodales finibus massa, eget hendrerit erat ultrices eu. Ut blandit tincidunt mattis. Suspendisse id
      varius diam. Quisque eget tincidunt ante, sed sodales neque. Nulla quis libero eleifend, ultricies justo
      scelerisque, ultricies odio. Vestibulum sit amet justo dui. Nunc rutrum diam velit, accumsan dictum elit
      dignissim in. Maecenas vitae eros pellentesque, sollicitudin nunc congue, commodo velit. Fusce ut semper
      risus. Nullam bibendum, nisi et mattis pretium, arcu nulla ultrices magna, non suscipit nibh augue non magna.
      Duis maximus lorem eget nibh fermentum, et ultricies nisl efficitur. Nam ac libero orci.
        </p>
        <p>
          3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras lobortis eros quis arcu vulputate ultricies.
      Fusce sodales finibus massa, eget hendrerit erat ultrices eu. Ut blandit tincidunt mattis. Suspendisse id
      varius diam. Quisque eget tincidunt ante, sed sodales neque. Nulla quis libero eleifend, ultricies justo
      scelerisque, ultricies odio. Vestibulum sit amet justo dui. Nunc rutrum diam velit, accumsan dictum elit
      dignissim in. Maecenas vitae eros pellentesque, sollicitudin nunc congue, commodo velit. Fusce ut semper
      risus. Nullam bibendum, nisi et mattis pretium, arcu nulla ultrices magna, non suscipit nibh augue non magna.
      Duis maximus lorem eget nibh fermentum, et ultricies nisl efficitur. Nam ac libero orci.
        </p>
        <p>
          4) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras lobortis eros quis arcu vulputate ultricies.
      Fusce sodales finibus massa, eget hendrerit erat ultrices eu. Ut blandit tincidunt mattis. Suspendisse id
      varius diam. Quisque eget tincidunt ante, sed sodales neque. Nulla quis libero eleifend, ultricies justo
      scelerisque, ultricies odio. Vestibulum sit amet justo dui. Nunc rutrum diam velit, accumsan dictum elit
      dignissim in. Maecenas vitae eros pellentesque, sollicitudin nunc congue, commodo velit. Fusce ut semper
      risus. Nullam bibendum, nisi et mattis pretium, arcu nulla ultrices magna, non suscipit nibh augue non magna.
      Duis maximus lorem eget nibh fermentum, et ultricies nisl efficitur. Nam ac libero orci.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="acptMsg">
      <ion-grid class="grid">
        <ion-row justify-content-center>
          <ion-col col-1 align-self-center>
            <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="concorda" class="checkbox"></ion-checkbox>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-8>
            <div class="confirm_msg">Eu li e concordo com os Termos e Condições/Política de Privacidade.
            </div>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </div>

    <div class="send_div">
      <button ion-button [disabled]="!concorda" class="send_button" full large>Finalizar</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

**css:**

```
page-contrato {
    #contrato {
        .main {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;

            .head {
                text-align: center;
                height: 20vh;
                top: 0;

               .logo {
                   height: 10vh;
               }

                .title {
                    padding: 0.7rem 0;
                    font-size: 4.3vw;
                }

            }

            .inner {
                top: 20vh;
                bottom: auto;
                height: 60vh;
                width: 90vw;
                margin: 0 5vw;
                border: 1.5pt solid black;

                .inner-main {
                    top: 0;
                    bottom:0;
                    left: 0;
                    right: 0;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%; 
                    text-align: justify;
                    overflow: auto;
                }
            }

            .acptMsg {
                top: 0;
                height: 8vh;
                max-height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                margin-bottom: 0;

                .grid {
                    margin-top: 10px;
                    margin-bottom: 0px;
                    height: 100%;
                    width: 100%;
                }

                .confirm_msg {
                    font-size: 2vh;
                    text-anchor: start;
                    text-align: justify;
                }
            }
            .send_div {
                position: fixed;
                width: 100%;
                top: auto;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;

               .send_button {
                    color: white;
                    margin-top: 2rem;
                    margin-bottom: 0;
                    background-color: color($colors, blue);
                    font-size: 1.6rem;
                    font-weight: 500;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

A solução se encontra na classe `.inner` e `.inner-main`. Apesar de definir um `top`, `bottom`, `left` e `right` iguais a `0` na classe `.inner-main`, se não for definido `width` e `height` `= 100%` o texto sai dos limites da `div` `.inner` e passa a ocupar toda a tela disponível.

Dessa forma, se o texto interno for maior que o espaço delimitado pela `div` ela tem o `scroll`só naquela região. E não precisa de um `<ion-footer>` e um `<ion-header>`.